# Imprimir en papel el contenido de una tabla sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite3

¿Como imprimir en papel todo el contenido de una tabla sqlite3?, solo puedo imprimir una linea de texto y nada mas, el resto de pagina de papel se queda en blanco.

```py
def imprimir(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
        cursor   = conexion.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TablaVentas")
        cursor.fetchall()

        for Columna in cursor:
            print (Columna[0],Columna[1],Columna[2])

        nota = QTextDocument(Columna[0],Columna[1],Columna[2])
        impresora = QPrinter()
        dialogo = QPrintDialog(impresora)
        impresora.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)
        impresora.setPageMargins(5,5,5,20, QPrinter.Millimeter)

        if dialogo.exec_() == True:
            nota.print_(impresora)
```

Comment: Ese codigo no deberia imprimir nada sino lanzar una excepción

Comment: NO TENGO NI IDEA DE COMO HACERLO. Coloque el código porque es obligatorio.

Comment: 1) Evite de usar los CAPS, ya que no son necesarios, 2) debiste señalar que ese codigo no funciona. 3) ¿Cual es el código con que dices *solo puedo imprimir una linea de texto y nada mas*?' ¿o son mentiras?

Comment: En el código hay dos partes funcionales, solamente no tengo ni idea de como conectarlas. La primera en una impresión simple en pantalla de todo el contenido de la tabla, la segunda parte imprime todo lo que se encuentra en el QTextDocument(). repito, no tengo ni idea !!, por eso estoy aquí preguntando para ver si alguien que sabe y tiene experiencia en esto me puede ayudar.

Comment: ¿O debería publicar el problema ya resuelto para ver si asi me puede ayudar alguien?

Comment: Calmate, nadie esta en contra tuya. Mi comentario iba en relación a que lo que señalas no concuerda con el código que provees. En tu pregunta señalas que al menos con el código que muestras puedes imprimer una linea pero claramente la linea: `nota = QTextDocument(Columna[0],Columna[1],Columna[2])` debe lanzar un error por lo que debe imprimirte nada.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya encontré la solución en otro sitio, solo vieron el problema y alguien me dijo como lo había resuelto el. Nada que ver con lo que yo estaba pensando. Me dio un ejemplo claro y muy diferente a lo que yo había planteado. Muy inteligente la respuesta que me dieron.

Comment: Si ya encontraste la solución entonces deberias publicar la respuesta inteligente :-)

Comment: En cuanto termine lo que estoy haciendo, no es algo simple para mi, estoy en eso que todos los que recurren a esta pagina (aprendiendo).

Comment: Samuel saludos, Comentaste en una respuesta que ya conseguiste el código, te agradecería que me lo compartieras, yo también estoy buscando imprimir una base de datos.